# IIS hosting in windows server 2012 r2

Tags: iis, hosting, windows-server-2012-r2

I am hosting my ASP .NET Core in Windows server 2012 R2. IIS Version 8.5

When I try to access the URL I get a 404 error:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

I installed all IIS features and also installed the ASP .NET Core hosting bundle, but it is not working. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have to correct .NET Framework installed on the server.